# Continuity of the sequence of averages

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Suppose you have a sequence of bounded continuous functions $f_n:(a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Then, define the function 
$$S(x)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nf_n(x).$$
Is $S(x)$ continuous?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem ?

Comment: I think you need some kind of uniformity in the continuity, eg consider $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $(0,1]$